# null-propagating operator returning bool

Tags: c#

I have a '`Func<bool> Filter`' delegate that returns a bool. However, the user of my class isn't required to supply this and if not supplied the default value should be true. If the Filter is null however, it's making result equal to false. I'm not sure why. I would think the statement would basically result in nothing happening and it remains true. What am I missing and how could I do this using this shorthand way, if possible. I know I could write this out differently but I'm trying to get the idea with this new shorthand way.

```
bool? result = true;
result = h.Filter?.Invoke(args);  // IF Filter IS NULL THIS LINE TURNS result TO FALSE

if (result != null || result == true)
{
    yield return h.Callback(args);

    h.Post?.Invoke(args);
}
```

Comment: It can't be making `result == false`. That's not what's happening here. If you test `result.HasValue` you will get `false`.

Comment: `if(result ?? true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what your code does. Specifically, your if statement.

When `h.Filter` is `null`, you are effectively assigning `null` to result:

```
bool? result = null;
```

Now if we were to test your "true" statement, we would see this:

```
Console.WriteLine("!= null: {0}", result != null); // != null: false
Console.WriteLine("== true: {0}", result == true); // == true: false
```

Therefore your condition is not satisfied.

It seems that what you really wanted is this (`== null`, rather than `!= null`):

```
if (result == null || result == true)
```

Which can be more succinctly written as:

```
if (result.GetValueOrDefault(true))
```

Comment: GetValueOrDefault() is what I was needing! Thanks for that. You are correct, but what's strange is VS when hovering over result says it's false, but digging deeper you are correct the HasValue is false but the value is null. That's interesting that hovering over would just say false like that. A little misleading given hovering over a boolean, even if nullable, you'd expect the editor to show you it's value not the HasValue value I guess. Thank you again!

Comment: @user441521 It's probably a bug with the debugger. You can report it to Microsoft by using the button left of the quick launch box in the top-right of the Visual Studio window.